# GA EC Event Tracking is often very slow, leading to poor UX

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-analytics, usage-statistics

I have just implemented the GA enhanced ecommerce events, for tracking product clicks. When user clicks on a product thumbnail, this event is sent.

This implementation is based on Google Analytics [guide for enhanced ecomm](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-click). I have also added profiling code using performance.now(). A skeleton is as below:

```
var addProductHandler = (function() {
    return function(ev) {
        var t1 = performance.now();
        ...
        ga('ec:addProduct', {
           'id': SKU,
           'position': item_position
        });
        ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: 'Prod Reco'});
        ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'Results', {
            hitCallback: function() {
                console.log('perf1:', (performance.now()-t1)*1000);
                document.location = _href;
            }
        });
        ...
    }
})();
```

During testing, I find that if I click on a product thumbnail soon after visiting that page, then the event gets pushed out in ~53ms. That's very good, no issue.

But If I delay that click to a longer period, say ~5 secs, then it takes anywhere between 1-2.5 secs!

This sluggish responsiveness will hurt user engagement.Trying to analyse this using Chrome, I find the below:

When the event is successfully sent in ~53 ms, 1 request like below is sent out:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j50&t=event&a=...
status: 200
```

But when it takes the longer 1-2.5 secs time, the transfers look like this:

```
1 https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j50&a=...
  status: 302
2 https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&aip=1&t=dc&_r=3&tid=UA-...
  status: 302
3 https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-...
  status: 302
4 https://www.google.co.in/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-...
  status: 200
```

This shows that there are 4 https request, first 3 with 302 redirect, and the final one doing the job. Each of them adds their own latency (DNS/initial connection/SSL/Waiting/Content Download) and they sum up to the mentioned 1-2.5 secs delay. Only after these 4 requests are completed, hitCallback will be called, which then starts to load the clicked product page.

Any help in avoiding this sluggish behaviour will be great. This delay as I understand is not something to expect or to happen.

(Note that I haven't yet introduced the [setTimeout](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#handling_timeouts) on hitCallback as that will only chop out transfers with delay beyond configured value, thus skipping those events.
Also note that in both the transfers, I see there's a request for 'gif' even though I have configured for transport:'beacon' in ga's 'create' routine).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by correcting the way I set transport as 'beacon'.

Based on google's (wrong) documentation [here](http://www.aplns.com/products/2420113425/kolorobia-mughal-dark-sipper), I had set `transport: 'beacon'` in ga's `'create'` call. It's not right and hence GA was not using 'beacon'.

Correct way is as mentioned in other places in GA's docs:

```
ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon');
```

Also note that GA is not sensing the best method available for using as transport. It should have used 'xhr' method which is synchronous POST using XMLHttpRequest, but was falling back to 'gif' GET (tested on Chrome 57.0).

To fix the issue, I am currently using the below JS code:

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.sendBeacon) {
    ga('set','transport','beacon');
} else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      ga('set','transport','xhr');
}
```

In really old browsers where XMLHttpRequest is not supported, like IE5/6, there hopefully GA will use the 'gif' method. We don't need to set 'transport' for them. However, we are not supporting those legacy browsers.